# MARIA DB query working fine whereas the same query doesn't work in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Can't find out what's the actual problem. i am using the below example which works fine in:

e.g:

```
select * from table where (( p1 = '' OR p2 = '') OR table_column BETWEEN p1 AND p2)

Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.0.31-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server
Protocol version: 10
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

but when i run the same query on:

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.6.37 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

it doesn't work! Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

p1 and p2 are parameters with the datatype YEAR and query is in a procedure.

Comment: It doesn't work??? Erorr/exception/no data/incorrect data/...

Comment: yea it doesn't show any results in server type: myql

Comment: yes i imported it

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=e36563695b4f8a6d2547df06c298ae2f) (MariaDB) and [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mUHA8mBiyfoR4hXSafnpPP/0) (MySQL).

Comment: @wchiquito actually p1 and p2 are the  parameters

Comment: The query is inside a stored routine?.

Comment: yes and the data type is year. i changed the type to varchar and it works but i am still confused why the year datatype is still working on MARIA DB

Comment: `p1` or `p2`, can they be an empty string?.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156689/discussion-between-abdal-asif-and-wchiquito).